# Computing matrix eigenvalues with units

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, units

I apologize if this is a basic question or if I am not giving enough detail. I'm trying to solve for the eigenvalues of a matrix with matrix elements that have units.

```
Sx = 1/Sqrt[2] {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
Sy = I/Sqrt[2] {{0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}};
Sz = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}};

S = {Sx, Sy, Sz};
B = {Bx, By, Bz};

Hm  = Mz MatrixPower[Sz, 2] + 
   Mx (MatrixPower[Sy, 2] - MatrixPower[Sx, 2]) + 
   My (Sx . Sy + Sy . Sx);

Hsimple = d MatrixPower[Sz, 2] + γs/(2 π) B . S + Hm;
TraditionalForm[Hsimple]
Hamil = Chop[
  Hsimple /. {Mx -> Quantity[0, "kHz"], My -> Quantity[0, "kHz"], 
    Bx -> Quantity[0, "Gauss"], By -> Quantity[0, "Gauss"] , 
    Mz -> -1*Quantity[74, "kHz"], d -> Quantity[2.87 , "Gigahertz"], 
    Bz -> Quantity[2, "Gauss"], γs -> Quantity[2.8, "Megahertz"/"Gauss"]}]
```

with output

```
{{Quantity[2.87553*10^9, "Hertz"], Quantity[0., "Hertz"], 
  Quantity[0, "Kilohertz"]}, {Quantity[0., "Hertz"], 0, 
  Quantity[0., "Hertz"]}, {Quantity[0, "Kilohertz"], 
  Quantity[0., "Hertz"], Quantity[2.86432*10^9, "Hertz"]}}
```

Ok cool. I could technically read off the eigenvalues since the matrix is obviously diagonal. However, when I use `Eigenvalues[Hamil]` to compute the eigenvalues it gives me something crazy:

```
{Root[Quantity[0., (
     "Hertz")^3] + (Quantity[8.23644*10^18, (
       "Hertz")^2]) #1 + (Quantity[-5.73985*10^9, 
       "Hertz"]) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
 Root[Quantity[0., (
     "Hertz")^3] + (Quantity[8.23644*10^18, (
       "Hertz")^2]) #1 + (Quantity[-5.73985*10^9, 
       "Hertz"]) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 Root[Quantity[0., (
     "Hertz")^3] + (Quantity[8.23644*10^18, (
       "Hertz")^2]) #1 + (Quantity[-5.73985*10^9, 
       "Hertz"]) #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong here; I'm not too experienced. It would be nice to use `Eigenvalues[]` for matrices that aren't diagonal.

Also, it's interesting to me that some of the 0 values retain their units. I have run into unit compatibility issues when these zeros are added to other non-zero values that have incompatible units.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Element `{2,2}` of your `Hmil` is 0 without unit, but others are kinds of Hertz (Kilohertz, Megahertz etc.), so it would be better to add unit to that 0: `ReplacePart[Hamil, {2, 2} -> Quantity[0, "Hertz"]]`. Now all goes well: `Eigenvalues[%]` gives `{Quantity[2.87082*10^9, "Hertz"], Quantity[2.86903*10^9, "Hertz"], Quantity[0., "Hertz"]}`.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! So it seems Mathematica doesn't like mixing units with unitless. I mean, makes sense but isn't quite obvious!